# How to do the move the images like marquee in html in iphone

Tags: iphone

i am developing one application.In that i have 10 images .i want to move that images from right to left like as a marquee effect in HTML.That images are moving infinite number of times.So please tell me how to move that images from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in @Dev's answer this can be done through animation, however if you're going to animate it theres no need to change the image if you only want to move it.

This code for example takes a photo of your choosing and moves it from the top left of the screen to the bottom left and can be modified to move right to left, and is already set up to repeat infinitely with `[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:-1];`.

In achieving a marquee effect, the best way I can think of to handle that would be to make the images fully animate off screen before the animation ends and resets, creating the illusion that the image went off one side of the screen and came in the other.

```
- (void)animateImage
{
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"myAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:-1];

//    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(callSomeThingElse)];

    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 50, 50)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
- (void)startAnimatingImages
{
    for (UIImage* aImage in yourImageArray)
        {
            [self animateLabelToTheRight:aImage];
        }
}

- (void)animateLabelToTheRight:(UIView *)yourView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                     animations:^{ view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 35, view.frame.origin.y, image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height); } 
                     completion:^{ [self animateLabelToTheLeft:yourView] } ];
}

- (void)animateLabelToTheLeft:(UIView *)yourView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                     animations:^{ yourView.frame = CGRectMake(yourView.frame.origin.x - 35, yourView.frame.origin.y, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height); } 
                     completion:^{ [self animateLabelToTheRight:yourView] } ];
}
```

Comment: needed some tweaking but this is the best solution for a marquee on views.

for example - you shouldn't move UIImage, but UIImageViews. the animation duration can be longer (the distance to move also larger of course) ...plus use UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear as animation options

Answer (score 0):

Animation is required for this type of moving image. if you try this code ,your problen is solve:

```
UIImageView *animationimage;

  animationimage.animationImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:

                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash1.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash2.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash3.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash4.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash5.png"],nil];

    // all frames will execute in 1.0 seconds
    animationimage.animationDuration = 1.0;
    // repeat the annimation forever
    animationimage.animationRepeatCount = 0;
```

remember one thing you have different sequential image is require link in my code splash%i.

i hope ,helpful for you.